# AWS SES- Using Feedback-ID(from the header) to get Notification Obj

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, email-bounces

Is there any way(APIs?) to get the Bounce/Complaint notification object(atleast bounce/feedback type) using Feedback-ID which we receive as one of the header of the 'Email Feedback Forwarding' email address.

ex. 
Feedback-ID: 1.us-east-a.BBHhIbbl0BUJpgbOscbsio9YJTpaNVCa6dKZ3gKK0Uxg=:AmazonSES

Thanks,
J.